# Как скрыть консоль на линуксе и винде

Tags: python

Вопрос такой хочу что бы после запуска приложения, не появлялось или сразу бы пропадало окно консоли. И все это нужно сделать програмно на python. Предполагаю что нужно использовать библиотеку os.

Comment: как вариант использовать расширение файла вместо `.py` на `.pyw`. Или скомпилировать файл при помощи библиотеки `cx_freeze`

Comment: Это для windows, для линукс это работать не будет, верно?

Comment: да по идеи должно работать и на `linux`, на счет `cx_freeze` не уверен в `linux`

Comment: В папке питона есть pythonw.exe и python.exe. Один из них с консолью открывает

Comment: Вопрос если скомпилить єтот файл в exe будет ли он работать на компьютерах без интерпритатора питона?

Comment: @ВладЛесной, будет работать, просто интерпретатор и все сопутствующие библиотеки будут зашиты в сам exe файл.